# Python homemade package import error after pip install

Tags: python, pip, package, python-import

If I make a very simple package like this (with empty `__init__.py` files):

```
package_name/
    package_name/
         sub_module/
              __init__.py
              file.py  
         __init__.py
    setup.py
```

When I start a Python shell at the root of this project, and do:

```
import package_name.sub_module.file
```

everything goes well and I can use the functions in `file.py`. But if I send this project on a GitLab, and pip install it in another local project and import it the same way, I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package_name.sub_module'
```

I tried to modify the `__init__.py` files in many ways but I can't find something working. I don't understand why this happen.

**EDIT:** Here is the content of the `setup.py` file:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='package_name',
      version='0.1',
      description='My package',
      url='https://gitlab.myserver.com/package_name',
      author='Me',
      author_email='me@myserver.com',
      license='MIT',
      packages=['package_name'],
      install_requires=[
          'another_package_1',
          'another_package_2'
      ],
      zip_safe=False)
```

To install the package with pip, I use the command:

```
pip install git+https://gitlab.myserver.com/package_name.git
```

Comment: The root of the problem is probably inside the `setup.py` or in your installation steps. What argument did you pass to `setup()`? What commands did you type to install the package? Without that it's impossible to tell what is going wrong.

Comment: I bet it's the `packages` kwarg. Do you call your `setup` function with  `packages=['package_name']`?

Comment: I followed the instructions in the basic pip tutorial about packaging. I'll edit the question tomorrow with its content. Yes I use the package=['package_name'] command.

Comment: I just found out the 'packages=find_packages(exclude=['contrib', 'docs', 'tests*'])' option. I think I misunderstood the way packages are declared. If I had to do it manually, does it mean I have to write packages=['package_name', 'package_name.sub_module' ?

Comment: @debzsud exactly, you have to list *all* the packages explicitly by their full names. Including `foo` does not imply including `foo.bar`. It is advisable to use `find_packages` function from `setuptools` so you don't have to update the packages list every time you create a new package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look on this site https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html
you have to declare every subfolder in the project structure

packages=['an_example_pypi_project', 'tests'],

```
|-- an_example_pypi_project
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- useful_1.py
|   |-- useful_2.py
|-- tests
|-- |-- __init__.py
|-- |-- runall.py
|-- |-- test0.py
```

---

```
|-- an_example_pypi_project
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- useful_1.py
    |-- subfolder
|   |   |-- useful_2.py
|-- tests
|-- |-- __init__.py
|-- |-- runall.py
|-- |-- test0.py
```

packages=['an_example_pypi_project', an_example_pypi_project.subfolder, 'tests'],